# How to change Fedora 14 dual-monitor default behavior (No clone)

Tags: linux, xorg, multi-monitor, xrandr, laptop

I am running Fedora 14 on my laptop, and I use it either with or without an external screen.

```
[nbarraille@barraille ~]$ xrandr | grep " connected "
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 190mm
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
```

When the VGA screen is plugged in, every time I reboot, the system sets it up so that VGA1 is a clone of LVDS1 and I have to do a:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1
```

How can I change it to be the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Gnome, try using System->Preferences->Monitors.  KDE has a similar tool in System Settings->Display.
I don't know if hot-plugging makes any difference, but this tool will save your settings so anytime you reboot it'll use the same settings as last time.

Comment: I am using KDE. I did try the System Settings>Display, changed it there and applyed "Set to Defaults" but it doesn't work and everytime I reboot, it resets to "Clone"

Comment: I think the "Set to Defaults" option reverts any changes you've made.  It doesn't create a new default.

Comment: In the menu Save as Default, you have two options: Save as Default and Reset. I assumed that Set as Default should set the current configuration as Default.